# How to combine tabs and action bar navigation in Android?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I'm coming from the iOS world and need to port an app with the typical tabbar/navigation pattern to Android. The UI design is the client's decision, so I can't change it (I'd still like to hear from you if you think it's appropriate or not for Android).

So the idea of the app is the following:
3 Tabs are always shown on the bottom of the screen. Inside each tab there can be a hierarchy of screens, with the title and up-button showing in the action bar on the top.
How do I implement this in Android? Am I correct in that the tabs need to be a fragment which need to be implemented in every single activity? How should the hardware back button behave? Say if I switch to a certain tab and then press the back button, should the tab change back or should it mirror the up-button's functionality?

As you can see I'm struggling with all these basic concepts and I'm very thankful for any tip that can help me to implement this navigation structure.

### Edit:

Thanks to the competent answer of CommonsWare and looking deeper into it, I realise that I really should push the client to use an UI that's more suitable for the platform. (Also, I know I should use an Android device for some time to get used to the concepts, but I can't change that for now. So I'm sorry for these newbie questions).

The thing is, the app existed before as a web container app with an ugly jquery mobile UI with the above described UI elements. The idea is now to make the app navigation native with native animations, while keeping the content views in html/css/js inside webviews. So while it's possible to adapt each platform's UI principles, I cannot change the general structure of the app, which is: 3 different main entry points, and in each of them the content is navigated hierarchically. I've implemented that in iOS with a tabbar and navigation controllers which works great. The challenge is now to implement it in Android. To reassure that I'm on the right path and understood the points of CommonsWare correctly as well as to maybe receive more tips, I'm writing down what my thoughts on the steps involved:

As CommonsWare suggested, I could replace the tab idea with action buttons in the action bar, which will work well as there are only 3 of it. So it's appropriate to use action buttons for navigation? There will be an additional button for switching the language (Yes I know, usually I should pick the current language of the system, but in this particular app language switching is important and the user will switch it several times while using the app). To separate the navigation action buttons from the language switcher, which works on the current content and is a bit less important, I put the language switcher under the so-called "action overflow" (the 3 dots on the upper right corner).

Now there is an action bar button for each "tab", so far so good. But is there a way the user can tell on which "tab" he is? Or should I only show two action bar buttons at any given time, hiding the one he's currently "in"?

Each of these action bar buttons starts a new activity (with it's own action bar, right?). Inside such activity, the user can navigate hierarchically and back using the up button or back button. He can also use the hardware back button to go back to the last "tab"; would this be appropriate?
Every screen in the navigation hierarchy is a separate activity with a title and a webview.

In the end, to make the whole app compatible back with gingerbread, I would use the actionbarsherlock library, right?

Answer (score 2):

> 3 Tabs are always shown on the bottom of the screen

That [violates the Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html). On Android, [tabs go at the top](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html).

> Inside each tab there can be a hierarchy of screens

Outside of a Web browser, I truly detest this navigation concept.

> Am I correct in that the tabs need to be a fragment which need to be implemented in every single activity?

You do not appear to have more than one activity in your proposed design.

> Say if I switch to a certain tab and then press the back button, should the tab change back or should it mirror the up-button's functionality?

And this is one of the reasons why I truly detest in-tab navigation. Tabs are for *presentation* of content, not as a navigable container in their own right.

> should it mirror the up-button's functionality?

Since you do not appear to have more than one activity, it is unclear to me that you even have an up button.

> How do I implement this in Android?

Ideally, you dump the tabs and use [action bar items](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) to switch between the different navigable areas, each of which would be its own activity. In that case, back (and to a lesser extent up) will flow more naturally.

If you had more than three tabs, you might go with [the navigation drawer pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), with the navigable areas each having an entry in the drawer. Three, though, would make the drawer look rather empty.

There is plenty more on [app structure](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html) in the Android design guidelines that can help.

---

> The UI design is the client's decision, so I can't change it

The objective of an app is to allow the users to accomplish their objective. Using design patterns native to a platform help in this regard, by allowing the users' existing experience to guide them in the use of the new app. This is not to say that true innovation beyond the guidelines is inappropriate, but it requires experience and deft hand.

Your client appears to be saying, "hey, this one firm came up with a design pattern for their platform, so therefore let's use it everywhere, as we want a consistent UI design". The problem is that **nobody cares** about consistency between platforms except them. Few people own mobile devices from multiple platforms, let alone use the same app on both, let alone expect the same UI design on both. Certainly, design touches (e.g., color scheme) could be similar, and the objectives of the app will be similar if not identical. But the *delivery* of that functionality should use design metaphors and patterns that are native to each platform, as the user is *far* more important than is your client.

(and if your client says "well, we are the users", because this is an internal-use-only enterprise app, kindly explain to them the concept of the passage of time, introduce them to the notion of employee turnover, and point out that they won't be the users all that long compared to the possible lifetime of the app)

Your client, if they ran a US-based car rental agency, would argue that their firm should rent [left-hand-drive cars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-_and_left-hand_traffic) in the UK, for a consistent UI experience, despite all the accidents that will cause in a left-hand-*traffic* country.

---

Now, let's pretend for a moment that you need to write this app following their UI design anyway. Hostages are being held at gunpoint, somebody has a nuke on a hair trigger, the bad guy is demanding the app, [the clock is ticking, you're Kiefer Sutherland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_%28TV_series%29), and so on.

(and if you really *are* Kiefer Sutherland, ummm... hi!)

You will wind up with a single activity for this core UI. Ancillary stuff (e.g., preferences, help) would be separate activities, but the three-tabs-to-rule-them-all UI would be in one activity.

The tabs themselves probably would use a `FragmentTabHost`, perhaps with modifications to better support tabs on the bottom. This is not a common choice, but it's the best fit. `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator would be another possibility, if the client does not consider a horizontal swipe to change tabs to be "the devil's gesture" or something. Action bar tabs are at the top and are not always tabs, as they sometimes convert to drop-down navigation in certain screen size and orientation combinations.

Each tab would be a fragment and most likely would use nested fragments for the in-tab navigation between panes of content. Again, there are other possibilities (e.g., lots of hiding and showing of widgets within a single fragment to handle the navigation), but I think you'll go crazy trying to manage all of that.

With respect to the BACK button, without knowing the context of the tabs, my gut instinct would be to follow the tabbed browser metaphor of "BACK is local to a tab". I think that you'll need to manage this manually, unless it magically works because you are using nested fragments, and I don't think that's the case. When you are at the beginning (nested) fragment for a tab, and the user presses BACK, exit the activity.

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful answer! I've edited my question(s) above and I would highly appreciate it if you could comment on it again